# Eclipse bug? Switching on a null with only default case

Tags: java, eclipse, null, enums, switch-statement

I was experimenting with `enum`, and I found that the following compiles and runs fine on Eclipse (Build id: 20090920-1017, not sure exact compiler version):

```
public class SwitchingOnAnull {
    enum X { ,; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = null;
        switch(x) {
            default: System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled and run with Eclipse, this prints `"Hello world!"` and exits normally.

With the `javac` compiler, this throws a `NullPointerException` as expected.

So is there a bug in Eclipse Java compiler?

Comment: Have you raised a bug over at eclipse.org?

Comment: Or post in the eclipse forum.

Comment: @Rulmeq, @fastcodejava: see my answer. Bug accepted, assigned, candidate for 3.6.1.

Comment: @poly - no offense meant. Good that you posted here as well.

Comment: See also http://www.riedquat.de/blog/2011-03-04-02

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a bug. Here's the specified behavior for a `switch` statement according to the *Java Language Specification, 3rd Edition*:

#### [JLS 14.11 The `switch` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11)

> ```
> SwitchStatement:
>     switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock
> ```
>
> When the `switch` statement is executed, first the `Expression` is evaluated. If the `Expression` evaluates to `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown and the entire `switch` statement completes abruptly for that reason.

Apparently the bug in Eclipse has nothing to do with `default` case or `enum` at all.

```
public class SwitchingOnAnull {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        java.math.RoundingMode x = null;
        switch(x) {};

        switch((Integer) null) {};

        switch((Character) null) {
            default: System.out.println("I've got sunshine!");
        }       
    }
}
```

The above code compiles and runs "fine" on (at least some version of) Eclipse. Each individual `switch` throws a `NullPointerException` when compiled with `javac`, which is exactly as the specification mandates.

---

#### The cause

Here's `javap -c SwitchingOnAnull` when compiled under Eclipse:

```
Compiled from "SwitchingOnAnull.java"
public class SwitchingOnAnull extends java.lang.Object{
public SwitchingOnAnull();
Code:
 0: aload_0
 1: invokespecial  #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
 4: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
 0: aconst_null
 1: astore_1
 2: getstatic     #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 5: ldc           #22; //String I've got sunshine!
 7: invokevirtual #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
10: return

}
```

It seems that the Eclipse compiler gets rid of the entire `switch` constructs entirely. Unfortunately this optimization breaks the language specification.

---

#### The official words

The bug has been filed and assigned for fix.

> Olivier Thomann      2010-05-28 08:37:21 EDT
>
> We are too aggressive on the optimization.
>
> For:
>
> ```
>   switch((Integer) null) {};
> ```
>
> we optimize out the whole `switch` statement when we should at least evaluate the
>   expression.
>
> I'll take a look.
>
> Candidate for 3.6.1.

#### See also

- [Bug 314830 - Switching on a `null` expression doesn't always throw `NullPointerException`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314830)

Comment: weird. how would Eclipse cause this bug? Doesn't Eclipse use java and javac behind the scenes?  very interesting.

Comment: That's funny. Some EDT developer was a bit *too* smart when implementing an optimization it seems.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be registered as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?type1-0-0=substring;field1-0-3=status_whiteboard;short_desc=compiler%20switch%20enum%20null;field0-0-0=product;field1-0-2=short_desc;type0-0-1=substring;field0-0-1=component;type1-0-1=substring;type1-0-2=substring;type1-0-3=substring;type0-0-3=substring;query_format=advanced;field0-0-3=status_whiteboard;short_desc_type=allwordssubstr;field0-0-2=short_desc;type0-0-0=substring;field1-0-0=product;type0-0-2=substring;field1-0-1=component . So you could create a ticket there.

Comment: @darren no. Eclipse has its own compiler, entirely separate from `javac`. Do a stackoverflow search for "eclipse javac" and you'll see there are a number of cases (especially related to generics) where they behave differently.

Comment: @aioobe - You're correct, they're too smart. They implemented it in such a way that makes sense when the language definition doesn't. Throwing an exception rather than going to default is definitely retarded. Now I have to wrap a try/catch for a NullPointerException where the catch will do the exact same thing the default does. Edit: Actually, I'll insert a null check, it's quicker than waiting to catch the exception, particularly since it's expected.

Answer (score 4):

Definitly. If we look at the [chapter 14.11](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11) of the java language specification, it clearly states (under 'discussion'):

> The prohibition against using null as
>   a switch label prevents one from
>   writing code that can never be
>   executed. If the switch expression is
>   of a reference type, such as a boxed
>   primitive type or an enum, a run-time
>   error will occur if the expression
>   evaluates to null at run-time.

Comment: I can imagine a better rule: 1. allow a `null` switch label not covered by `default`, 2. issue a warning/error whenever the `null` label is missing and the expression is not a primitive. 3. enjoy shorter code and zero risk of NPE in switch.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. According to the JLS it's a bug:

> If the switch expression is of a reference type, such as a boxed primitive type or an enum, a run-time error will occur if the expression evaluates to null at run-time.